# Python multiprocessing.Pool map() "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am attempting to use multiprocessing.Pool to do parallel processing on a list of dictionaries.  An example is below

(**Please note**: this is a toy example, my actual example will be doing cpu-intensive processing on the values in the actual dictionary)

```
import multiprocessing

my_list = [{'letter': 'a'}, {'letter': 'b'}, {'letter': 'c'}]

def process_list(list_elements):
    ret_list = []
    for my_dict in list_elements:
        ret_list.append(my_dict['letter'])
    return ret_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    letters = pool.map(process_list, my_list)
    print letters
```

If I run the code above, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocess_fail.py", line 13, in <module>
    letters = pool.map(process_list, my_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 250, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I don't know what string indices it is referring to.  Shouldn't `pool.map` just be iterating over the items in `my_list` (i.e. the dictionaries)?  Do I have to alter how the data is being passed to the map function to get it to run?

Comment: `my_dict` is `'letter'` for each iteration of `map`, `list_elements` is a single `dict` not the whole list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pool.map()` takes a callable and an iterable, then proceeds to apply the callable to each element in `iterable`. It'll divide the work across the pool workers in chunks, but the function will only ever be passed *one* element at a time.

You passed in a list of dictionaries, which means that each `process_list()` is passed **one** dictionary:

```
process_list({'letter': 'a'})
process_list({'letter': 'b'})
# etc.
```

Your code however is treating the `list_elements` as a list. The `for` loop:

```
for my_dict in list_elements:
```

instead sees dictionary keys, each `my_dict` is bound to a key at a time. For your dictionaries, that means there is one iteration, and `my_dict` is set to `'letter'` each time. The line:

```
my_dict['letter']
```

then tries to index into that string, and `'letter'['letter']` throws the exception you saw.

The following works:

```
def process_list(list_element):
    return list_element['letter']
```

You'd return *one* result; `map()` gathers all results into a new list and returns that when all workers are done.