# TypeError: string indices must be integers for Multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, string, int, multiprocessing, typeerror

I'm trying to figure out how to use multiprocessing, but having an issue with the following code. When running the `pool_testing()` function I get a `TypeError`. I tried changing `pool = multiprocessing.Pool()` to `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n)`, but same error. Can anybody please help?

```
import multiprocessing  

profile = [{u'firstName': u'Karen', u'age': 20},
           {u'firstName': u'Jon', u'age': 25}] 

def testing(profile):
    for i in profile:
        print ("Hey " + str(i["firstName"]) + "!")

def pool_testing():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(testing, profile)

pool_testing()
```

Traceback:

```
File "/System/.../multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411424/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-n) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python multiprocessing.Pool map() "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411424/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-n)

Answer (score 1):

[`pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) automatically *maps* each item of the iterable argument to the function, so you don't need to do it manually (`for i in profile`) -  `profile` is already the item your interested in. The relevant line in the function description:

> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks.

So, in your case your `testing` function would look like:

```
def testing(profile):
    print "Hey " + str(profile["firstName"]) + "!"
```